# Eclipse - Adding folder as package not working

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I'm using Eclipses' `Build Path -> Configure Build Path` to add a `Library` that contains some legacy code I have from and old application. However, whenever I `Add Class Folder`, the package structure it creates isn't correct.

I need the folder structure `symantec\itools\db\beans\binding` to create the package as `symantec.itools.db.beans.binding`, containing all the .java files listed in the image below.

Folder Structure before `Add Class Folder`:

[image]

Package structure after `Add Class Folder`:

[image]

Any suggestions are welcomed! I feel like I'm loosing my mind on this :(...

Comment: you can manually added files on folder using your window explorer than clean your project to see changes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, actually, when I right-click on the folder and do 'Use as Source Folder', the packages are created correctly, but it doesn't include the .class files. Adding them manually doesn't seem to help